# Highcharts image export with HTML labels not working

Tags: highcharts, linegraph, react-highcharts

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xtds1wLh/6/

This is just an example JS Fiddle
Here I have specified: useHTML: true in xAxis labels

and have also specified: allowHTML in exporting
Render looks good but when exported the css property does not gets applied and Test 1 and Test 2 appear in single line

```
    exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        allowHTML: true,
        chartOptions: {
            chart: {
                height: 400,
                width: 1000
            },
            xAxis:{
            allowHTML: true,
            }
        }
    }
```

Export should be same as render

Comment: I am aware about a workaround by using <br> tags but it introduces too much gap in my use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `allowHTML` is an experimental setting and not all of its applications may function properly.

However, the problem is related to the fact that the export server doesn't have access to your CSS. As a solution, you can add inline styling. For example:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: [
    '<span style="display: block;"><span style="display: block;">Test 1</span><span>Test 2</span></span>',
    'Feb', ...
  ],
  labels: {
    autoRotation: false,
    useHTML: true
  }
},
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yh9n47m3/

**Useful thread:** https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=43159

**Docs:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowHTML